# Unicode 6.0 + React PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, progressive-web-apps

I have got this array:

```
hearts: [
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
  ];
```

In desktop I can see each symbol render, but in my android phone I cant see any.
I have already tried to change font to a custom one and find a local one but none of this helped.

Comment: The custom font has all the symbols? Did you try with a web font?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I tried all fonts in https://fonts.google.com/ and none of them support this unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some search I find this font: https://fontlibrary.org/es/font/symbola ,
which supports unicode 6.0 and so playing cards.